# seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid object at <dirección de memoria>

Tags: seaborn

Estoy tratando de crear un histograma con *Seaborn* y cada vez que hago un ejemplo me sale el siguiente error:

```
<seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid object at 0x00000176C376BD10>
```

¿Qué significa eso?

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ¿Tenés la certeza de que efectivamente es un error? ¿Te lo muestra en consola?

Comment: Fijate por ejemplo en [estos ejemplos en Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/residentmario/faceting-with-seaborn) y buscá ese texto. Tal como dice la edición del título, nada más te está mostrando en qué dirección de memoria está el objeto. **Es un mensaje de información, no de error**.